# Argument 2: cannot convert from System.IO.FileInfo to 'string'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am getting an error when I try to open up the most recently made text file in a certain repository.

> "Argument 2: cannot convert from System.IO.FileInfo to 'string'"

The error is underlined under "newestFile".

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(Program.resultsFolder);
var newestFile = directory.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).First();
Process.Start("notepad.exe", newestFile);
```

Anyone have any ideas on why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That makes sense, since `GetFiles` returns an array of `FileInfo` objects, and you're selecting the first one. `FileInfo` contains a lot more info about the file besides the name.

If you want to access the file's path, you'll have to use the correct property.

Assuming the file is a txt file, and notepad is the default app for that type, just use `FullName`:

```
Process.Start(newestFile.FullName);
```

Answer (score -1):

Process.Start takes two strings as parameters.  Your original code is of type fileinfo.  Need to convert to string

```
var newestFile = directory.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).First().ToString();
```